# How to concatenate url + string + value ? ruby

Tags: ruby

Trying to parse through all pages in category of products. I want to check every page using original_url+'&p='+value, where value is number of pages.

`How to write this properly` full_source = url + "&p=" + "#{number_of_page}" ``

Comment: Did your code work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
full_source = "#{url}?p=#{number_of_page}"
```

Your question had an ampersand:

```
full_source = "#{url}&p=#{number_of_page}"
```

A better way to do it would be:

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({ p: number_of_page })
puts uri.to_s # URL with query params
```

Here is an example:

```
url = 'http://google.com/search'
uri = URI.parse(url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({ q: 'ruby' })
puts uri.to_s
# => "http://google.com/search?q=ruby""
```